# How to process how many items can be purchased(int) and how much money left over (double)

Tags: c++, division, modulus

I am trying to write a code that ask the user how much money they have and how much the item cost they want to buy. Then it will tell them how many of the item they can buy and how much money they will have left over. I am a beginner and not sure what to do. The modulus operator is only giving me 0.00 and when I take away the (int) in front of my variables it give me an error. I want them as doubles but it gives an error.Thank you.

void howMany (double &amtMoney, double &itemCost)
    {
    int amtItem;
    double remainingMoney;

```
cout << "Please enter amount available and cost of each   ";
cin >> amtMoney >> itemCost;
if(amtMoney < 0)
{
    cout << "Invalid price " <<endl;
}
else
{
    amtItem = amtMoney / itemCost;
    (double)remainingMoney = (int)amtMoney % (int)itemCost;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "You can buy " << amtItem <<
    " and have " << remainingMoney << " left over. " <<endl;
    cout << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: You should not use binary floating-point types such as `double` for monetary amounts. This is going to waste your time. Use an integer type to represent a number of cents.

Comment: Worse than wasting some of your time - you can very easily get inconsistencies.

Comment: The leftover amount would be `amtMoney - amtItem * itemCost`.  You could use the `fmod` or `remainder` functions to calculate this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sure what type `amtMoney` and `itemCost` are, but you can use `fmod` to safely evaluate a remainder. You just need to include `cmath` library.

Also, you don't need to write `(double)remainingMoney` cause `remainingMoney` is declared as double.